# Put players in spectator on death

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to put players into spectator mode when they die, at the location they died at.

My current attempt involves tracking player deaths using a scoreboard variable that increases on death. When said scoreboard value is positive, I reset it and set the player spawnpoint to their current location. I also set the player into spectator mode. I set the gamerule `doImmediateRespawn` to true.

Sadly, Minecraft often refuses to respawn the player since the location they died at is "invalid".

How do I make players respawn into spectator mode in the location they died at?

Comment: Can you show us the syntax for this command? The "invalid" location might not be taking into account the z level perhaps?

Comment: `spawnpoint ~ ~ ~` on player death. Players tend to die in invalid positions a lot.

Comment: Again, if you could post the command(s) you are using, we can use that to potentially figure out a more valid command to achieve your glaos :)